# How do you prevent Word Find.Execute() from going into an endless loop?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, word-interop

I am writing a Word add-in using .NET and VSTO.  I need to search a footer for all instances of some text.  I am looping with Word's Find.Execute() as shown below.  It goes into an endless loop when it matches the text in a content control in a table cell in the footer.  It keeps going back to the same range.

Why would this code cause an endless loop?  How can I tell Word to continue searching after this point?

```cs
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...
Word.Range range = headerFooter.Range;
Word.Find find = range.Find;
while (find.Execute(FindText: wildcard,
                    MatchWildcards: true,
                    Forward: true,
                    Wrap: Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(range.Start + ", " + range.End);
}
```

The code gives output like this:

```
192, 206
192, 206
192, 206
```

I tried collapsing the range to the end of the match inside the loop as follows, but it still loops forever back to the original range.

```cs
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(range.Start + ", " + range.End);
    range.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
}
```

I am running Word version **Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2205 Build 16.0.15225.20028) 32-bit**.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance, I was able to fix the issue by advancing the range to the beginning of the next table cell.  I based this on the second post in this forum thread: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/40986-infinite-loop-when-finding-styles.html

Here is the code that fixed it in this instance.  It may not fix it in every situation:

```cs
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...
Word.Range range = headerFooter.Range;
Word.Find find = range.Find;
while (find.Execute(FindText: wildcard,
                    MatchWildcards: true,
                    Forward: true,
                    Wrap: Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop))
{
    results.Add(range.Duplicate);

    // WARNING: In skipping the remainder of the table cell,
    // we could be skipping additional matches.
    if (range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdInContentControl] && range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdWithInTable])
    {
        int endOfCell = range.Cells[range.Cells.Count].Range.End;
        range.End = endOfCell;
        range.Start = endOfCell;
        if (range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdAtEndOfRowMarker])
        {
            range.End += 1;
            range.Start += 1;
        }
    }
}
```